# Axios header doesn't work Laravel and Vue.js

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, axios, bearer-token

I'm using Laravel's Sanctum library to authenticate my API, but it just doesn't work and everything seems on purpose.

I'm creating a token after someone authenticates, and it goes into `personal_access_token` table in database. And then I insert the token into metatag. Then I retrieve the content of the metatag with default javascript (it works) and set it as global authorization header to Axios in `bootstrap.js` file.

When using the decrypted bearer token, this approach was working. But when I started to use the default *token* column on `personal_access_token`, it doesn't work.

**The way I define my token**

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {
        $user->access_token = $user->createToken('api-token')->plainTextToken;

        return $request->wantsJson() ? response()->json($user, 200) : redirect()->intended('/students');
    }
```

That works good. It inserts new token after someone authenticates.

**The way I set token as content of metatag**

```
<meta name="access-token" content="{{auth()->user()->tokens()->first()->token}}" />
```

I can see the token when I inspect, it is like this: `fd34a554cc5a6f14004f8728735375f980d81053b97f719be5bd504647d786cf`

**The way I set the token as global header to Axios**

```
let metatag = document.querySelector('meta[name="access-token"]').content;

window.axios = require('axios');

axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${metatag}`;
```

There were no problem with that, until I switched to `personal_access_table`. That approach was working when I used a token like `6|yqbI...`.

That is returning a 401 error right now, when I click to that I can see my token like `Authorization: Bearer fd34a554cc5a6f14004f8728735375f980d81053b97f719be5bd504647d786cf` in Request Headers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I use the hashed token as global header I got error.

But I've added this line to .env file `SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost:8000`

Since my localhost has a port, I needed to define it manually in .env file

That solution worked for me.